# Pubnub: Issue with Push Notification

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, chat, pubnub

I am using Pubnub for a chat based Application.

Consider a scenario where **Alice** initiates a chat with **Bob**.
Flow at Alice's end for initiating a new chat:

- Subscribe newChannel
- Add to your own channel group
- Create **Bob's** channel group
- Add newChannel to Bob's channel group
- Unsubscribe Bob's channel group

Since Bob is now subscribed to this newChannel he receives the messages from Alice.
**But Bob's device is not registered to receive push notifications for the channel.**

If the app in Bob's phone is not running Bob does not get a push notification for these messages and the messages is missed.

**Need a work around to notify Bob that he has received a message from some new user.**

App is running on both platforms iOS & Android and the chat is between a customer and service-provider. Important for the service-provider to be notified when receives a message from a new customer.

Flow working fine when receives a message from a existing thread since in this case device is registered to receive push notifications for this particular channel.

Comment: Registering for push notifications is separate from subscribing to channels or channel groups. You just need to register Bob to each channel (not channel group) for push notifications and he will always receive the push notification. Therefore, no issue at all :)

Comment: That flow is working fine. Issue is I am able to register Bob to notifications ONLY from Bob's device. When the app is not running on Bob's device, he does not get the push to notify that he has received a message from some new customer.

Comment: Please see the [Mobile Push Troubleshooting Guide](https://support.pubnub.com/support/solutions/articles/14000043605-how-can-i-troubleshoot-my-push-notification-issues-), and if you still have issues/questions, report all important data you gathered from that troubleshooting to [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com). We'll post solutions back to this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Registering for push notifications is separate from subscribing to channels or channel groups. You just need to register Bob to each channel (not channel group) for push notifications and he will always receive the push notification.

Please see the [Mobile Push Troubleshooting Guide](https://support.pubnub.com/support/solutions/articles/14000043605-how-can-i-troubleshoot-my-push-notification-issues-), and if you still have issues/questions, report all important data you gathered from that troubleshooting to PubNub Support.